# How to implement "atomicity" for a series of operations? (not necessarily multithreading related)

Tags: design-patterns, atomic

### The Problem

My programm has an operation which consists of a series of single operations that all change global state. Each of the elementary operations can fail and leave the global state in an undefined state.

### The Question

Is there a generic pattern that helps me to make the composed operation "atomic" in the sense that if one of the suboperations fails, the global state is left unchanged?

I use C++, so if answers contain code, please prefer that language if you have a choice. But I do not mind examples in other languages.

### Comments

- This resembles the "atomicity" of a database, where you add all or nothing when doing a commit. How is that implemented?
- In my case my global state is the state of the file-system. I need to add or remove multiple files at once and want to make sure that they are all added or nothing is added.

### My Thoughts

The best I can come up with is a class that gets a list of operations and their inverse operations. If any of the operations fails, it executes the reverse operations of the already executed operations. But what to do if one of the reverse operations fails?

How would the interface of that class look like? Would I have an extra class that resembles an reversible operation? Do you know a place where I can read more about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic solution is commit-or-rollback.

The generic C++ implementation is to build a list of objects supporting 3 methods:

- `run()` which will perform all the steps which *could* fail, without producing *visible* side-effects. It must throw without changing *anything* if it fails
- `commit()` which may not throw, and must only make the steps performed during `run()` visible
- `rollback()` which may not throw, and must only undo the steps performed during `run()`

and then iterate over that list calling `run()` on everything. If any throw, catch it and `rollback()` everything that ran successfully. If none throw, `commit()` them all.

---

Approximate workflow for your situation is - for each file-creating-object:

1. call `run()` to create (and populate?) the file in the correct directory, but with a temporary name - ideally hidden

   - if this fails, call `rollback()` on each successfully `run()` file-creating-object. This must delete the temporary file and may not fail.

     Then, give up, retry from scratch, prompt the user or something.
2. repeat #1 until you've created all files
3. they all succeeded, so call `commit()` on each object. This must rename the temporary file to its final name and may not fail

This requires that the `commit` step cannot fail. In this case, that assumes renaming a file can't fail - you have to ensure this is really true (ie, there are no name collisions) *before* you get to the `commit` stage.

---

Note this *does* have intermediate non-atomic changes - the only way to avoid that in general is to have two copies of the global state, and an atomic swap to commit the modified one. You can't do this for a filesystem in general, even if you're writing the driver.

Comment: I will try implementing your solution because it is similar to what I had in mind myself, and it is nicely described. But I don't fully understand why the commit() function is necessary. Is this to prevent others from messing with the half-done state while the various run() functions are beeing called?

Comment: In general use the run step is required to be local/invisible and reversible, but the commit step is global/visible and may not fail. Using hidden files is the best approximation we can get for files, but the general case includes building a new local copy of some global object(s) - which may throw - and swapping the local and global copies of each object, which may not.

Answer (score 1):

When I first read your question, I pictured something like this:

```
bool ApplyStateTransitions(Transitions& transitions) {
   auto lock = BlockUntilLocked(); // begin critical section
   auto clone = mCurrentState.Clone(); // copy all the state
   auto success = clone.ExecuteTransitions(transitions);
   if (!success)
      return false;
   mCurrentState = clone;
   return true;
}
```

You could do a similar approach with an immutable state pattern.

Typically copying the current state in a state machine is not that expensive; they just don't have that many states. Or is it more like a database table?

Database engines use a transaction with rollback or commit approach. You can read about that approach here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: What you suggest is probably the "copy and atomic swap" aproach that Useless mentiones at the bottom of his post. He also says that it is not applicable for changes to the filesystem, but maybe it will be usefull at some other point.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) EAA design pattern.

Comment: The text in the link is too short for me to really understand the pattern. Guess i have to get fowlers book.... But this is only what he wanted anyways ;-). I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) article that describes the pattern in more detail, but I am still not sure if this is what i want. I think my problem is on a lower level than the problem that the Unit of Work pattern tries to solve. But I can not be sure because I have not completly understood the pattern.